# linux select call in socket programming

Tags: c, sockets, select

In most Unix systems, typing ctrl-d indicates EOF on standard input. What happens if you type
ctrl-d to the program while it is blocked in the call to select ? Here Select is with reference to event based Socket programming in C.

```
select(maxfd+1, &readfds, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: it will treat the ctrl-d as an standard input only !!

Answer (score 0):

If a file descriptor is closed, select will return and indicate that the file descriptor is ready to be read.  The subsequent read will return 0, indicating an end of file condition.